# Union in view breaks dropdownlistfor in mvc 5

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5

This View

```
alter View [dbo].[vwQTCustomers]
as 

select distinct top 100 percent
Customer,
Name,
isActive
from (
select
    'testA' 'Customer',
    'testA' 'Name',
    convert(bit, 1) 'isActive'
UNION ALL
select
    'testB' 'Customer',
    'testB' 'Name',
    convert(bit, 1) 'isActive') A
```

returns in SSMS.

```
Customer    Name    isActive
testA   testA   1
testB   testB   1
```

When I add this to my drop down list in MVC, I just get two 'testA' results.

Model:

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> customers = db.vwQTCustomers.Where(w => IsActive == true).ToList().Select(w => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = w.Customer.ToString(),
            Text = w.Name
        }).OrderBy(w => w.Text);
```

View:

```
      <div class="editorMedium">
                        @Html.Label("Customer:")
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.selectedCustomer, Model.customers, "-- Select Customer --", new { @class = "dropdown dropdown-toggle btn btn-default", @id = "customer" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.selectedCustomer)
      </div>
```

Originally this view contained just a single table and it worked fine.  The issue appears to be the union statement but I can't figure out why.  Any ideas?

Comment: What is the issue? Your question title says "it breaks". What does that mean? And why do you have distinct and top 100 percent on there?

Comment: The dropdown returns two results both with the text of 'testA'.  It does the same thing regardless of the distinct and top 100 percent.

Comment: Right...the distinct and the top 100 percent are pointless. The outer query isn't providing anything either. And wrapping derived column names in single quotes is not a good habit. It really makes your code confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query with the same results but simplified a lot. There is no need to use a subquery, distinct or top 100 percent here. I still don't actually understand what the problem is that you are running into.

```
select
    Customer = 'testA',
    Name = 'testA',
    isActive = convert(bit, 1) 
UNION ALL
select
    'testB',
    'testB',
    convert(bit, 1)
```

Comment: The query is not the issue, the results return correctly as I stated in the original question.   I wrapped the union into a subquery just to see if I could trick MVC into working.  The issue is with MVC and the dropdown.

Comment: I get that the error is in MVC but I don't understand what the issue is. I posted this because the query you have is overly complicated for such a simple thing and we longer than a comment would allow.